# Преобразовать результат collection.Counter() в список пар (кортежей)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Дано:

```
res_interest = ['Прыжки с парашютом', 'Прыжки с парашютом', 'страйк-бол', 'фантастика']
```

или

```
res_interest = Counter({'Прыжки с парашютом': 2, ' страйк-бол': 1, ' фантастика': 1})
```

Необходимо получить следующий список:

```
result = [('Прыжки с парашютом', 2), ('страйк-бол', 1), ('фантастика', 2)]
```

Comment: я не уверен, что понял вопрос. Остановить в дебаге и посмотреть тип переменных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого у словарей есть функция [.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), которая вернет пары ключ-значение:

```
from collections import Counter

res_interest = Counter({'Прыжки с парашютом': 2, ' страйк-бол': 1, ' фантастика': 1})
print(res_interest)
print(list(res_interest.items()))
# [('Прыжки с парашютом', 2), (' страйк-бол', 1), (' фантастика', 1)]
```